# Different bg on specific wordpress page with ajax page loader

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, wordpress

Live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr2-2

I'm trying to build a one page wordpress theme with ajax page loading.
Using "ajax advanced page loader" plugin. 
First i was stuck with loading two circles on the home page after coming back from other pages. It simply refused to display them. So, i just inserted all the code into a post and it worked. But now, i've got another problem. I have a content background, and since this circles are also in content div- main page displays that background as well. And I need to get read of it.

Code for the home page template

```
<div class="container">
<div id ="content" id="homepagewrap">
    <?php
$post_id = 1;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
?>
<p><?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Regular page code

```
<div class="container-full pagebg">
<div id="content" class="pagecnt">
    <?php the_post(); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <div class="entry-content">
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
.pagecnt {
padding: 50px;
width: 100% !important;
margin-top: 40px;
}

.pagebg {
margin-top: 200px;
background-color:rgba(49,49,49,0.90);
color: #fff;
}
```

I tried next piece of css, but it made the rest of the pages bg transparent as well as main page.
    .home>.pagebg {
    margin-top: 200px;
    background-color:rgba(49,49,49,0);
    color: #fff;
    }

Don't really have any other ideas. Jquery? Something else with css?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Loading a different BG or are you having issue with the CSS?

Comment: Loading a different bg

Comment: I want to get rid of this grey strip (post bg) on the front page.

Comment: Remove the backgruond color for this class (.pagebg)

Comment: How do i keep the background for the rest of the pages then?

Comment: You can bind to the onclick event of "?page_id=X" and change it show/hide it accordingly.